# How would a curved sensor change camera and lens design?

Tags: lens-design, cmos-image-sensor, technology-generations

I've read that lenses are designed to project an image onto a flat surface and that as image sensors grow larger, lenses will grow correspondingly larger and by some additional factor. Flat imaging was clearly important in the early days of photography where an image was projected onto the actual display medium as with Daguerreotypes.

Additionally, flat image projection certainly simplified film photography, where images could be conveniently stored on a rolled-up, long flat strip.

But why are we still projecting images onto flat surfaces if neither the storage medium, or the processing requires it?

Wouldn't lens design be vastly simplified if the image were projected onto a curved sensor? Shutters faster and more efficient if they were located at a fixed point? Is the problem with CCD design and sensor manufacturing? Are manufacturers pursuing this at all? Or are we destined to luggage-sized cameras.

Comment: If you remove a constraint from engineers they should be able to make other things better.  If not, it really wasn't a constraint.  I would think this would happen in fixed lens cameras first because you don't need a full suite of lenses designed to the (same) curved plane and don't risk customers buying the wrong sort of lens and being disappointed.  The question is whether it helps enough to create a path through the sensor industry that grinds the blank to a curve before making a sensor.

Comment: Are you asking about sensors curved in a single plane (as in cylindrical curvature) or in 2 planes (spherical curvature)?

Comment: Like the eye's retina....curved around the x and y axes, lightpath down the z axis.

Answer (score 12):

Digital image sensors used in modern cameras are [essentially silicon chips](https://thinklucid.com/tech-briefs/understanding-digital-image-sensors/):

> Sensor dies are produced in large batches on silicon wafers. The wafers are cut into many pieces with each piece housing a single sensor die.  The larger the sensor die size, the lower number of sensors per wafer.

The wafers are [sawn with diamond saws from silicon ingots](https://svmi.com/service/silicon-wafer-manufacturing-process/), which renders them flat. I can only imagine that trying to saw or otherwise cut a surface curved in two dimensions would be very hard or impossible. Consequently, the "natural state" of a digital sensor is flat.

#### Image of two such wafers

[image: a big wafer and a little wafer]

*(Image by Hebbe at German Wikipedia, via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Siliziumwafer.JPG).)*

However, the raw wafers undergo considerable "post-processing" like polishing which conceivably could be used to grind one surface into a concave shape; but of course the succeeding processes currently are expecting a plane surface, so one must expect all kinds of costly adaptations and problems down the road.

That said, [Canon has filed a patent for a curved sensor](https://photorumors.com/2016/12/10/canon-curved-self-bending-sensor-patent-plus-curved-sensor-advantages-and-benefits/). I suppose that if the chip is thin enough it is flexible enough for the purpose.

Comment: You can easily bend Si wafers if you want to. By a little bit when they are 100 um+ and by quite a lot when it is down to about 40 um thickness. Unfortunately, it is very fragile plus there are issues fabricating high quality thin wafers in anything resembling cost effective way. So, what you save by lens in weight and cost would be lost by extra vibration dampening in the body and costly lens repair would be replaced by even more costly sensor replacement.

Comment: @Zizy What you see sometimes is cylindrical bending (e.g. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Thin-silicon-wafers-can-be-bent-without-inducing-fracture-7_fig1_3930675) Spherical/hyperbolic shapes will have a much larger bend radius.

Comment: Silicon chips being flat is also an artifact of the flat focal plane used in the photolitography processes.

Comment: @fraxinus I can imagine that it would be easier to have a curved focal plane there, too! But the wafer [is sawn with a diamond saw from a silicone ingot](https://svmi.com/service/silicon-wafer-manufacturing-process/). I have no clue whatsoever how to turn that into an image sensor but I suppose that's how it starts... seems impossible to saw a 3D-curved shape.

Comment: There is nothing impossible with 3d cutting shapes, but yes, it will be orders of magnitude harder (and expensive).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Could that problem be avoided by depositing the silicon directly onto a curved backplate, avoiding the intermediate ingot step?

Comment: @Vikki you need a monocrystal for the chip. This is why ingots are made in the first place.

Comment: @fraxinus: You could also get a monocrystal by depositing the silicon onto the curved backplate and then annealing the assembly at a temperature high enough for the individual crystals in the silicon layer to merge into one.

Comment: @Vikki it wouldn't be a very good crystal with a curve and without lattice matching.  Far easier would be to cut a thick wafer and polish it as we do lenses.  In fact [this is done for infrared optics](https://www.edmundoptics.co.uk/f/silicon-plano-convex-pcx-lenses/14248/) where silicon  is transparent.  As Peter says, deposition onto the curved surface would be problematic, but again, the optics industry does that for things like anti-reflection coatings.  All this would make for very expensive sensors.

Comment: @Vikki I'm no expert on monocrystal Si but you usually need a perfect seed crystal to start the process. The Si crystal structure is diamond shaped, so it doesn't want to bend. You use annealing to remove stresses from a wafer. So it would "pop back to square and flat" if you heat it.  If I remember correctly the electrical characteristics of a semiconductor will actually change depending on the plane in which the monocrystaline Si was cut. With a theoretical curved crystal structure, you don't have this plane which I  would cause some problems in analogue applications like photography.

Comment: ... (also @Max) [apparently](https://physicsworld.com/a/curved-camera-chips-may-be-the-next-leap-in-astronomical-imaging/) thinned and bent sensors are showing promise (Physics World article; the researchers actually started from commercial CMOS sensors.)

Comment: @ChrisH That's pretty cool. But they used a flat sensor and bent it afterwards. I didn't mean that Si can't be bent, just that it doesn't want to grow bent. Now, organic semiconductors might do the trick ;) But I doubt they'll replace Si-CMOS anytime soon...

Comment: @Max my previous comment at a similar time to yours suggested grinding and polishing to shape. I half-recalled the article and thought that was how it was done, but I was wrong (and your comment appeared while I was refreshing/correcting my memory).

Comment: Growing thin enough bent could be done in an interesting way - grow on a thin substrate with a compatible lattice structure and a slightly larger constant (perhaps GaAs or GaP) and the resulting structure will be curved with a curvature depending on the 2 thicknesses. You might start with a thick substrate and thin it from the back.  Normally Si is used a substrate for exotic semiconductors and this *bowing* is a problem.

Comment: @ChrisH that's a cool idea. I would love to see NASA try something like that in a "screw it, money is not an issue" operation. Everyone else will just get slapped in the face by TSMC if you hand them a bowed wafer ;)

Comment: @Max thinking further, an issue with very flat laser mirrors and especially beamsplitters is the optical coating causing tiny but detectable  amounts of bow. Balancing coats on the back are sometimes used as are thicker optics.  I wonder what would happen to a very thin wafer with front coatings and an un-balancing coat on the back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134367/discussion-between-max-and-chris-h).

Answer (score 10):

Curved film planes were very common in low-end roll film cameras and even 35 mm simple cameras.

This is because they improve the image quality of a lens with a spherical focal surface, as is the case with the simplest lenses used in consumer cameras back in the day -- the meniscus.  Meniscus lenses were common as far back as wet plate days (1850s on), and were popular because they were cheap.  Kodak sold the Vest Pocket Kodak with an achromatic meniscus, but did what was necessary to use a flat film plane: installed the lens concave to the world, behind the aperture and shutter.

Later, for marketing reasons, meniscus lenses were often installed the other way around, convex to the world, which allows placing the lens in front of shutter and aperture and avoids "the lens has fallen off!" conversations at the camera store.  Unfortunately, that way 'round a meniscus has a curved focal surface; this was compensated, especially in rectangular frame formats, by constraining the film surface to a cylinder which minimized the error, mostly confining defocus visible on the contact prints of the day to the extreme corners of the frame.

This "optimization" for lens cost is very unlikely to appear in digital cameras, however, because it would be offset by the costs associated with fabricating a non-planar sensor surface.  Designing lenses with flat focal plane is old news; the Cooke triplet, Periskop, Rapid Rectilinear, and Tessar all have flat focal plane, and predate the introduction of roll film as we know it in 1901.

If you want to look it over, however, try to find one of the "plastic fantastic" 35 mm cameras that have been sold over the past fifty or so years.  Ilford and Lomography sell them now as "reusable" (as opposed to disposable) cameras, at prices around US$30 to US$50, and cheaper examples can be had direct from China.  All of these have simple meniscus lenses and curved film planes.

Answer (score 7):

It's not like there isn't any research being done in this direction:

[Origami silicon optoelectronics for hemispherical electronic eye systems](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-01926-1)

> ...reshaping conventional planar sensor systems into hemispherical formats would empower visual recordings with features that are beyond what state-of-the-art cameras can see, such as infinite depth of field, wider view angle, and lower aberrations

These guys have taken rudimentary silicon imaging technology and folded them into curved shapes, mimicking insect eyes:

[image]

Admittedly, their results are fairly primitive but the paper is already over 4 years old. Modern CCDs also had humble beginnings!

Comment: Those incorporate the lens and sensor together -- each sensor fragment has its own lens, like an insect's compound eye.  Not at all the same.

Answer (score 1):

*Or are we destined to luggage-sized cameras.* If you consider what can be done with mobile phone cameras, we're really not.

Using that sort of technology and a small sensor we can already build a fixed focal length, fixed aperture, variable focus camera only about 1cm thick.  Applying this to a dedicated camera, with other advances from the last couple of decades, we should be able to get the image quality of an SLR from say 20 years ago in a small compact.

But then you hit an ergonomic limit.  Cameras have to be held steady, and the controls have to be operable with human hands.  Compacts without viewfinders, just like phones, have to be held tens of cm in front of your face, which makes them prone to shake.  Viewfinders take up space, and good ones as on SLRs take up a fair bit.

So there's not much demand  to make cameras even smaller than we already can.  If you want *small*, just use the phone you're probably already carrying.  If you want *good quality*, you can do pretty well with something that will fit in a pocket.  Bulky cameras get you versatility, including better performance over more metrics in a wider range of situations.

Curved sensors are of interest in astronomy.  In space-based telescopes [they could improve the quality in a given payload](https://physicsworld.com/a/curved-camera-chips-may-be-the-next-leap-in-astronomical-imaging/).

Comment: Understood. But keeping things from getting bigger is different from making things smaller. Demand for higher resolution and resulting larger sensors is forcing lenses to grow huge. Let's not even look at fast lenses for full frame cameras....OMG! Not to mention how impractically heavy some of these zoom lenses have become. As I understand it, that's driven by the physics of planar image projection.

Comment: Most of it isn't driven by the need to project an image onto a plane.  A little bit of bulk and a little bit of weight are, but that's all. Sensor sizes haven't changed in decades (full frame matches 35mm film) and higher resolution comes from smaller pixels instead.  There is some demand for faster lenses, and those are bigger

Comment: Admittedly, that's a good point. I also get that modern lenses also contain image stabilization and autofocus technology. But modern CCD resolution is far superior to film; might that require far better (and bigger?) lenses. The fact that unlike film, CCDs require a very specific light path also forces a specific lens design.